# How to merge audio and video file using ffmpeg in python?

Tags: python, ffmpeg

I need to merge both audio and video using ffmpeg in python 3.7,could you help me to solve this issue?

Here i used code :

```
from pathlib import Path
glob_path = Path(r"D:\t")
file_name = [str(pp) for pp in glob_path.glob(r'**/*.mp4')]
print(file_name)

video_stream = ffmpeg.input(file_name[0])
audio_stream = ffmpeg.input(file_name[1])
print(video_stream)
print(audio_stream)
ffmpeg.output(audio_stream, video_stream, 'out.mp4').run()
```

I getting this out put error

```
['D:\\t\\audio.mp4', 'D:\\t\\video.mp4']
input(filename='D:\\t\\audio.mp4')[None] <b0ebefda3dca>
input(filename='D:\\t\\video.mp4')[None] <388c87446fd1>


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\LENOVO\PycharmProjects\calc_new\udownlod.py", line 18, in <module>
    ffmpeg.output(audio_stream, video_stream, 'out.mp4').run()
  File "C:\Users\LENOVO\PycharmProjects\calc_new\venv\lib\site-packages\ffmpeg\_run.py", line 320, in run
    overwrite_output=overwrite_output,
  File "C:\Users\LENOVO\PycharmProjects\calc_new\venv\lib\site-packages\ffmpeg\_run.py", line 285, in run_async
    args, stdin=stdin_stream, stdout=stdout_stream, stderr=stderr_stream
  File "C:\Users\LENOVO\Anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py", line 775, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "C:\Users\LENOVO\Anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py", line 1178, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

Comment: You're getting a `FileNotFound` error, this is not really relevant to ffmpeg. I'd suggest looking into [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) to help deal with the filepaths

Comment: Hi, could I know any other way to give file path correctly ?

Comment: Please see the link I sent above @NASK

Answer (score 0):

Looks like one of the files cannot be found. The best thing to do is to check if both files exist at the specified locations.

```
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

Comment: Hi, I double check file is having in that directory , could I know how to add path ffmpeg.input("path"), if I used wary is wrong

Answer (score 0):

Even though it was shown path error, that error was in installation package, i used

```
conda install -c menpo ffmpeg
```

in https://anaconda.org/menpo/ffmpeg , solved my issue